# How to change the location of _spark_metadata directory?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured Streaming's streaming query to write parquet files to S3 using the following code:

```scala
ds.writeStream().format("parquet").outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                .option("queryName", "myStreamingQuery")
                .option("checkpointLocation", "s3a://my-kafka-offset-bucket-name/")
                .option("path", "s3a://my-data-output-bucket-name/")
                .partitionBy("createdat")
                .start();
```

I get the desired output in the s3 bucket `my-data-output-bucket-name` but along with the output, I get the `_spark_metadata` folder in it. How to get rid of it? If I can't get rid of it, how to change it's location to a different S3 bucket?

Comment: It will be solved by this PR: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/40821

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My understanding is that it is **not** possible up to Spark 2.3.

1. The name of the metadata directory is always [_spark_metadata](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSink.scala#L33)
2. `_spark_metadata` directory is always at the location where `path` option points to

I think the only way to "fix" it is to report an issue in [Apache Spark's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues/SPARK-24530?filter=allopenissues) and hope someone would pick it up.

### Internals

The flow is that `DataSource` is requested to [create the sink](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L309) of a streaming query and takes the `path` option. With that, it goes to create a [FileStreamSink](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSink.scala#L87). The `path` option simply becomes the [basePath](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSink.scala#L92) where the results are written to as well as the metadata.

You can find the [initial commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/6bc4be64f86afcb38e4444c80c9400b7b6b745de) quite useful to understand the purpose of the metadata directory.

> In order to correctly handle partial failures while maintaining exactly once semantics, the files for each batch are written out to a unique directory and then atomically appended to a metadata log.  When a parquet based `DataSource` is initialized for reading, we first check for this log directory and use it instead of file listing when present.

Comment: .compat file in _spark_metadata  folder keep on increasing and result in Job kill due to lack of memory.Is there any way we can /delete/discard older .compat files