# _spark_metadata causing problems

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Spark with Scala and I have a directory where I have multiple files.

In this directory I have Parquet files generated by Spark and other files generated by Spark Streaming.

And Spark streaming generates a directory *_spark_metadata*.

The problem I am facing is when I read the directory with Spark (`sparksession.read.load`), it reads only the data generated by Spark streaming, like if the other data does not exist.

Does someone know how to resolve this issue, I think there should be a property to force Spark to ignore the *spark_metadata* directory.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (Spark 2.4.0), and the only way I am aware of is to load the files using a mask/pattern, something like this

```
sparksession.read.format("parquet").load("/path/*.parquet")
```

As far as I know there is [no way to ignore this directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50847512/2390083). If it exists, Spark will consider it.