# Two Spark structured streaming jobs cannot write to same base path

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Spark Structured Streaming doesn't allow two structured streaming jobs to write data to the same base directory which is possible with using dstreams.

As _spark_metadata directory will be created by default for one job, second job cannot use the same directory as base path as already _spark_metadata directory is created by other job, It is throwing exception.

Is there any workaround for this, other than creating separate base path's for both the jobs.

Is it possible to create the _spark_metadata directory else where or disable without any data loss.

If I had to change the base path for both the jobs, then my whole framework will get impacted, So i don't want to do that.

Comment: Parametrisable location of `_spark_metadata` will be solved by this PR: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/40821. Then you can define different paths for `_spark_metadata` keeping data output one path for multiple jobs.

Answer (score 0):

No, changing the metadata directory name or location is not possible yet.
You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847512/how-to-change-the-location-of-spark-metadata-directory) for more information.

Could you eleborate why you will have to change model of your project for changing a path. Is the path hardcoded? Or are you reading this data in a particular manner no that would be affected?

Edit 1: You can use Partitions here. Example, if the data is stored as parquet you can have partitions in you base path. You can add a column "src" that has source of data, like SW1 for Stream writer 1 and SW2 for Stream Writer 2.

These will have below paths in hdfs:

1. <base-path>/src=SW1
2. <base-path>/src=SW2

Now your each job can directly write to their corresponding partition and your other jobs can continue reading from base path.

Comment: The base path is common for all the jobs, There are many jobs that will be reading data from the same base path(multiple sub folders inside). If I had to change the base path for one structured streaming jobs, then i will end up changing the base path for many other jobs which will be reading this data.

Comment: You can create two partitions in the base path, one for each kind of writer job. Your writer jobs should write directly to these partitions and still can read the base path without any modification in your reader jobs. Given your read data-model is not too rigid.